# Sind »deshalb« und »daher« austauschbar?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, conjunction

> Liebe ist eine sehr spezielle Sache, **daher** verliert sie nicht!
>
> Liebe ist eine sehr spezielle Sache, **deshalb** verliert sie nicht!

Was ist der Unterschied dazwischen und wieso? Danke!

Comment: Was der Unterschied zwischen zwei Wörtern ist, kann man relativ leicht anhand von Beispielen veranschaulichen. Aber die Frage wieso es diesen oder jenen Unterschied gibt, ist viel schwieriger, und vermutlich in vielen Fällen gar nicht zu beantworten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In deinem Beispiel sind beide Wörter austauschbar. Dies ist nicht immer möglich, obwohl sie Synonyme sind. Siehe Beispiele unten.

Auf die Frage warum die Wörter unterschiedlich sind kann ich leider keine Antwort bieten. Ich fürchte, dass es auch keiner vermag.

---

***deshalb*** wird [laut Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/deshalb) im Sinne von *daher* oder *aus diesem Grund* verwendet. Ein paar Beispiele davon:

- er ist krank und kann deshalb nicht kommen
- deshalb brauchst du nicht gleich beleidigt zu sein
- deshalb, weil …
- ach, deshalb also!
- sie machte es trotzdem oder vielleicht gerade deshalb

Insbesondere, obwohl *deshalb* und *daher* Synonyme sind, meine ich, dass im letzten Beispielsatz beide Wörter nicht vertauschbar sind. *sie machte es trotzdem oder vielleicht gerade daher* klingt sehr ungewöhnlich.

---

***daher*** hat darüberhinaus andere Bedeutungen. Aus [dem Duden entnommen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/daher).

im Sinne von '*von dort(her)*'

- bist Du auch daher?

im Sinne von '*hierhin*, *hierher*' (ist gebräuchlich, aber nicht populär)

- setz dich daher

im Sinne von '*durch diesen Umstand*'

- die Krankheit kommt daher, dass er immer den Staub einatmen muss

Ich denke im letzten Beispielsatz kann man *daher* nicht durch *deshalb* ersetzen. Sicher bin ich mir nicht.

Answer (score 2):

In der Bedeutung »*aus diesem Grund*« sind folgende Wörter Synonyme und können beliebig gegeneinander ausgetauscht werden:

- daher
- deshalb
- deswegen
- somit
- darum
- folglich
- infolgedessen
- also
- ergo
- (möglicherweise gibt es noch weitere Wörter in dieser Synonym-Gruppe)

Allerdings hat »*daher*« auch noch andere Bedeutungen:

**daher kommen** = aus einer Richtung kommen:

> Von wo kommst du jetzt **daher**?
>   Wenn du von dort drüber **daher** kommst, musst du am Museum vorbei gekommen sein.

**daher reden/sagen** = unbedacht reden:

> Das stimmt doch nicht! Was redest du für ein Zeug **daher**?
>   Nein, das meint er nicht so. Das hat er sicher nur so **daher** gesagt.

Comment: Ich würde "folglich, also, ergo, infolgedessen" rausnehmen da sie nur am Satzanfang funktionieren. Ausserdem gibt es insbesondere bei "folglich" Probleme mit dem feien tauschen. "Wir haben seinen Geburtstag vergessen. Mein Chef war deshalb/folglich (nicht das selbe) sehr sauer." "Mein Chef war sehr müde und wir durften deshalb/folglich früher gehen." , "Ich hatte Durst." Oh DESHALB/DARUM/DESWEGEN/DAHER/*ALSO/*FOLGLICH/*ERGO hast du mein Bier getrunken"

Comment: Vielleicht neigen daher viele (Altschreiber) dazu, _daher_-Verben zusammenzuschreiben.

Comment: @Crissov.. nee, ich glaube du hast Recht. Sonst würde es doch mit dem anderen "daher" kollidieren. "...dass ich daher geredet habe " vs. "... dass ich dahergeredet habe."

Comment: _mithin_ gehört auch irgendwie dazu, wird aber seltener als Konjunktion, sondern eher als bestärkende Partikel verwendet: _daher verliert sie mithin nicht_. Als reines Sprachspiel gibt es auch noch _*dieso_, um die volle Parallelität zu den (Sesamstraßen-)Fragewörtern herzustellen: _wieso? weshalb? warum?_

Comment: Ein Lerner, der diese Anwtort beim Wort nimmt wird teils sehr komische Resultate produzieren da die Hälfte der Wörter eben nicht einfach synonym ist. Da offenbar kein Anlass gesehen wurde nachzubessern jetzt -1.