# What is the difference between “somit” and “deshalb”?

Tags: meaning, difference, adverb

Below are the definitions provided by the Wiktionary:

- somit – therefore, hence, thus
- deshalb – hence, therefore

Is there any difference between these two words in terms of their meaning or how they should be used?

Comment: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/24405/1224

Answer (score 5):

*Deshalb* stresses that what was just said causes whatever is now following.

> Ich habe Höhenangst. *Deshalb* bin ich nicht geflogen.
>
> Es hat einen lauten Schlag getan. *Deshalb* sind die Pferde durchgegangen.

*Somit* on the other hand, is a lot weaker. There is still some kind of underlying continuity in the sense of cause → effect, but it is either very weak or not obvious or not important.

> Wir haben jetzt dreizehn Spieler im Verein. *Somit* können wir zwei Mannschaften aufs Eis stellen.
>
> Wir haben unser Tagessoll erfüllt. *Somit* können wir in den Feierabend gehen.

Trying to think of examples I realised that they are harder to invent for *somit*. I am inclined to say that it is the less common word.

Answer (score 1):

I know one case in which "deshalb" is preferred over "somit".

"deshalb" can also be used for "that's why ...":

(*pointing on something as your argument*)
That's why I never ride an elephant! 
Deshalb reite ich niemals auf einem Elefanten!

"somit" would be wrong.